# Find directory of a command in bash

Tags: bash

How do I find the directory of a command in bash?
I'm not looking `which`

For example `which cat` tells me `/bin/cat`.
I'm looking for something which only gives me `/bin`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dirname /bin/cat`

```
/bin
```

Similarly you can use `basename /bin/cat`

```
cat
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `bash` builtin string substitution:

```
CAT=$(which cat)
echo "${CAT%/*}"
```

Output:

```
/bin
```